# Vuejs how to declare a component in HTML before the #app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

For some reason I need to render a component in html, right before the div with the id #app which is needed by Vue.js to run.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Why? Can you not use CSS to position it wherever you want?

Comment: You make an excellent point and I thought about that. It's just that it's too much work to be done and CSS isn't quite my thing, so I wanted to ask if there's an easy way out of this..

Comment: I dont know for what reason you ask this.. but you can add a component before #app . for example try like this... in the component mounted 

`mounted(){

     let target = document.body;
    target.insertBefore(this.$el, target.firstChild)

}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Child component `mounted` you can insert the element before #app

```
 mounted() {
    document.body.insertBefore(this.$el, document.body.firstChild)
  }
```

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rk5ytqs3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [portal-vue](https://github.com/linusborg/portal-vue) to do that. There is [example](https://linusborg.github.io/portal-vue/#/guide?id=rendering-outside-of-the-vue-app) of how to render outside of the Vue app:

**Rendering outside of the Vue-App**

```
  <div id="app">
    <portal target-el="#widget">
      <p>
        PortalVue will dynamically mount an  instance of <portal-target> in place of the Element
        with `id="widget"`, and this paragraph will be rendered inside of it.
      </p>
    </portal>
  </div>
  <script>
    new Vue({el: '#app'})
  </script>
  <aside id="widget" class="widget-sidebar">
    This Element is not controlled by our Vue-App, but we can create a <portal-target> there dynamically.
  </aside>
</body>
```